# How can I store an information in an <img> or <a> tag to send later?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this img tag in an a tag which I'm using in a slider:

```
<a href="#" class="movie"><img src="images/1.png" alt="image01"></a>
```

I want to add movies to the slider in php and I know how to do that but how do I send information about the movie to a php file when they click on the image?

Like I have a movie.php file which I could make to get information through GET but how do I store and send the information to that php file when they click on the movie which will be an img tag.

Comment: If jquery has an easy answer for this I could use that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a **data attribute** to your tag.

For example:

```
<a href="#" data-movie="The Godfahter" class="movie"><img src="images/1.png" alt="image01"></a>
```

You can set any data attributes easy using **jQuery**:

```
$('a').data('movie', 'The Godfahter')
```

> data-* attributes allow us to store extra information on standard,
>   semantic HTML elements without other hacks such as classList,
>   non-standard attributes, extra properties on DOM, or setUserData.

If you don't know about data attributes check out [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

***AJAX GET Using jQuery [Updated]**

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '../movie.php',
  data: { id: $(this).data('id') },
  success: function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

Note that you need to wrap this code inside your click event.

Comment: Check out the answer, I have updated the code including an example of how tu make an AJAX Request using jQuery.